# Microsoft Teams bot: Card including Action.OpenUrl with task deeplink

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

For our bot in Teams, using the Microsoft Bot Framework, I want the bot to send a card with a button that, when clicked, will open a [task module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules) through a [deep link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules#task-module-deep-link-syntax)

Deep link:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/<BOT_ID>?fallbackUrl=https://google.com&completionBotId=<BOT_ID>&height=large&width=large&title=Title&card=<card>
```

Where `<card>` comes from the example in the docs:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Here is a ninja cat:"
        },
        {
            "type": "Image",
            "url": "http://adaptivecards.io/content/cats/1.png",
            "size": "Medium"
        }
    ],
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

URL encode the JSON to: `%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22AdaptiveCard%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22body%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22TextBlock%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22text%22%3A%20%22Here%20is%20a%20ninja%20cat%3A%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22Image%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fadaptivecards.io%2Fcontent%2Fcats%2F1.png%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22size%22%3A%20%22Medium%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22version%22%3A%20%221.0%22%0A%7D`

We then have deep link:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/<BOT_ID>?fallbackUrl=https://google.com&completionBotId=<BOT_ID>&height=large&width=large&title=Title&card=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22AdaptiveCard%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22body%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22TextBlock%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22text%22%3A%20%22Here%20is%20a%20ninja%20cat%3A%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22Image%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fadaptivecards.io%2Fcontent%2Fcats%2F1.png%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22size%22%3A%20%22Medium%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22version%22%3A%20%221.0%22%0A%7D
```

Finally, send message through Bot Framework API:

POST https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversations/<conv_id>/activities
Body:

```
{
    "recipient": {
        "id": "29:1uuzUvFTkcseXZ1Q2wOva1inGkpH1SqbHwqdXjG8MhUa8mkFsdUnvrgn4FnPbX8CwBl_GwDHSQGIlRSPKczwUFg"
    },
    "type": "message",
    "text": "Hi <br/><br/>What do you need?",
    "textFormat": "xml",
    "attachments": [
    {
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        "content" : {
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "actions": [{
                    "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                    "title": "Display task",
                    "url": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/<BOT_ID>?fallbackUrl=https://google.com&completionBotId=<BOT_ID>&height=large&width=large&title=Title&card=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22AdaptiveCard%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22body%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22TextBlock%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22text%22%3A%20%22Here%20is%20a%20ninja%20cat%3A%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22Image%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fadaptivecards.io%2Fcontent%2Fcats%2F1.png%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22size%22%3A%20%22Medium%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22version%22%3A%20%221.0%22%0A%7D"
                }],
    "body": []}}]}
```

The message appears in Teams as expected, but when clicking the button nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was sending my bot id instead of my app id for the APP_ID parameter.
I don't understand this in the docs though:

> Note that it's valid for APP_ID and BOT_APP_ID to be the same, and in many cases will be if an app has a bot since it's recommended to use that as an app's ID if there is one.

How is one supposed to achieve this?

Comment: When you create your bot in Azure, you have the ability to create it by supplying your own ID. Alternatively, you can just use the ID that's supplied. After that, when you create your Teams App, you again have the ability to supply an ID for the Teams App itself. Once again, you can supply your own value, so you could simply use the same value again. Personally, I'd avoid this as it leads to confusion - it makes one think that these are the SAME thing, when they're definitely not.